# Let $A$ be a set that is countable. Let there be a function mapping $A$ onto a set $B$. Is $B$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set that is countable. Let there be a function mapping $A$ onto a set $B$. I'm asked to prove the statement "$B$ is countable".

This is my attempt at a solution.

Since $A$ is countable it is either finite or countable infinite. 
If it is finite the statement is obvious. If it is countably infinite, it is by definition in one-to-one correspondence with the set $N$ consisting of positive integers. Since there exists a function mapping $A$ **onto** $B$, every element in $B$ has a direct relation to atleast one element in $A$, which in turn has a relation to $N$. And thus it $B$ must be countable since by proxy it is in one-to-one correspondence with $N$.

Does this logic prove anything, am I missing something? Am I completely on the wrong track and if so, how would I go about proving it? What happens in extreme cases if every element in $B$ is the image of a lot of elements in $A$?

Comment: You have to know what type of function mapping exists between $A$ and $B$ to say anything. If you know there exists a bijection $f: A\to B$, then you’re done.

Comment: @livingtolearn-learningtolive It is not clear that there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$. Does that mean the statement is false?

Comment: It is not true that $B$ must be in one-to-one correspondence with $N$. If the function is onto *but not into* (i.e. surjective but not injective), then it's possible $B$ has fewer elements than $A$ and is not in one-to-one correspondence with $N$.

Comment: The statement is false if "countable" only means "countably infinite", for in this case $A$ could be infinite but $B$ could be finite. (For example, let $A=\mathbb{N}$ and let $B=\{\text{even},\text{odd}\}$, and let the function map a number to its parity. This is surjective, but $B$ is finite.) But I think the definition of "countable" you're using must be "finite or countably infinite", right? In this case the statement is true.

Comment: Hint: a set is $X$ countable if and only if there exists a surjection $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to X$.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Yes my bad I am using the definition of "finite or countably finite". But I still cannot find a injective function $h : B \to N$. There does not need to be an inverse of the function from $A$ to $B$, right (since it is not injective)? So how can there possibly be a function injective function $h : B \to N$?

Comment: @Heuristics - Since you've got a bijection $\phi:N\to A$, you have a surjection $f:N\to B$ by composing $\phi$ with the surjection $A\to B$. If you don't mind using the axiom of choice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice), then you can get an injection $B\to N$ just by picking one element of $N$ that maps to each element of $B$. For each $b\in B$ you know there is at least one $n\in N$ with $f(n)=b$, because $f$ is a surjection, and you can use AC to pick just one such $n$ for each $b$.

Comment: I know for a fact that this question has at least two more duplicates.

Comment: @Ben: Why do you need the axiom of choice? I thought that the natural numbers were well-ordered even without assuming choice...

Comment: @AsafKaragila - you are right of course. I was sure there was a way to do it without choice but I was being lazy. Heuristics, Asaf is suggesting that you can construct your injection $i: B\to N$ by, for each $b\in B$, taking $i(b)$ to be the *smallest* $n\in N$ for which $f(n)=b$. Because "the smallest" is well defined on any nonempty subset of $N$, this construction does not rely on the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - maybe one of the other dupes would serve better as a link? It seems to me the answer at the linked dupe is tailored to the version of the question there, which has a different proof attempt. Like the OP, it's a request for proof verification, but the issues with that proof are different than the issues with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this doesn't analyse your proof. But here's how I'd approach proving the result. I'm using *countable* to mean *either finite or countably infinite.*

First we note that:

- $f$ is a function, so no element of $A$ maps to more than one element of $B$.
- $f$ is onto, so at least one element of $A$ maps to each element of $B$.

Whenever more than one element of $A$ maps to an element of $B$, let's just delete all but one of the mappings to that element, so only one element of $A$ maps to it. Now there are only one-to-one mappings.

Each deleted mapping leaves an element of $A$ unmapped, but every element of $B$ is mapped to.

So we've created a bijection between a subset of $A$ and the whole of $B$. But $A$ is countable, and any subset of a countable set is countable, so $B$ is in bijection with a countable set.

Therefore $B$ is countable.

---

**Edit:** This is almost the same argument as yours, and the answer to your last sentence is: just delete the extra mappings so everything's one-to-one, then look at what's left.

Answer (score 0):

How the proof proceeds depends on how you define "countable". A nonempty set $S$ is countable if either:

1) there exists a one-to-one function $f : S \to \mathbb N$, or

2) there exists an onto function $g : \mathbb N \to S$.

It turns out these are equivalent, so go with the second.

Since $A$ is countable there exists an onto function $g : \mathbb N \to A$, and by hypothesis there is an onto function $h : A \to B$. The composition $h \circ g : \mathbb N \to B$ is onto, so that $B$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Anytime you have a surjection from $A$ to $B$, it follows that $\mid A\mid\ge\mid B\mid$.

Intuitively this follows easily from the definition of *function*, since each element of the domain corresponds to exactly one element of the codomain.

Thus it would be easy to come up with a bijection between some, possibly proper, subset of $A$ and $B$, using Schröder-Bernstein, say, since you could get injections going both ways.

Answer (score 0):

It is true is that if $A$ is countable, $f:A \rightarrow B$, then $Im(f) \subset B$ is countable. And since you consider only surjective functions, $B$ is countable.

For a proof, it will depend on your definition of countable. For this problem the one that I find the most suited is:

A set $A$ is countable if and only if there exist a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

With it the proof is pretty straight-forward. Since by hypothesis $A$ is countable there exists a surjection $j$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$. Always by definition, $f$ is surjective onto its image. So $f \circ j$ gives you a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $Im(f)$ which means that $Im(f)$ is countable.

For your proof, there is a mistake in it in the end. You argue that you can have a one to one correspondence by "inverting" $f$ and composing it with the bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, but you forgot the case where the image of $f$ is finite. It does not affect the conclusion since a finite set is countable but it is a point to consider in your proof.

Comment: The OP did specify that the function $A\to B$ is *onto*.

Comment: Thank you, I edit my post. I didn't knew that the term onto meant that the mapping is surjective.